# Make ipython notebook print in real time

Tags: python, buffer, jupyter-notebook

Ipython Notebook doesn't seem to print results in real time, but seems to buffer in a certain way and then bulk output the prints. How can I make ipython print my results as soon as the print command is processed?

**Example code:**

```
import time


def printer():
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(5)
        print i
```

Supposing that the above code is in a file that is imported. How could I make it that when I call the printer function it prints a number every 5 seconds and not all the numbers at the very end?

Please note that I cannot edit the function `printer()` because I get it from some external module. I want the to change the configs of ipython notebook somehow so that it doesn't use a buffer. Therefore, I also do not wish to use sys.stdout.flush(), I want to do it in real-time according to the question, I don't want any buffer to start with.

I also tried loading ipython notebook with the command:

```
ipython notebook --cache-size=0
```

but that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks. My question is slighly different. I don't want to change the function printer() because I get it though importing a module which I don't want to change. I simply want to change the behaviour of ipython. So the solutions proposed in the above question don't work for me because I can't add  sys.stdout.flush() to the function. What I want is that there be no buffer in ipython notebook. That it outputs everything automatically.

Comment: You could monkeypatch the printer function.

Comment: Possibly, but there should be a way to unbuffer ipython notebook stdout no?

Comment: With the added requirement you can find [some answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't really find anything that works.

Comment: Title should be "Make ipython Notebook print in psuedo real time."  There is no such thing as Real Time in Python.  lol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Python 3.3, `print()` has an [additional flush](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) argument that can be used to force flushing:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 16):

This is merely [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231216/420867) to the question suggested by [Carsten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071311/carsten) incorporating the `__getattr__` delegation suggested by [diedthreetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234261/diedthreetimes) in a comment:

```
import sys
oldsysstdout = sys.stdout
class flushfile():
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __getattr__(self,name): 
        return object.__getattribute__(self.f, name)
    def write(self, x):
        self.f.write(x)
        self.f.flush()
    def flush(self):
        self.f.flush()
sys.stdout = flushfile(sys.stdout)
```

In the original answer, the `__getattr__` method is not implemented. Without that, it fails. Other variants in answers to that question also fail in a notebook.

In a notebook, `sys.stdout` is an instance of `IPython.kernel.zmq.iostream.OutStream` and has a number of methods and attributes not present in the usual `sys.stdout`. Delegating `__getattr__` allows a `flushfile` to masquerade as a `...zmq.iostream.OutStream` duck.

This works in a python 2.7 notebook run with ipython 3.1.0

Comment: It's quite a work around, but thank you! I will try it.

Comment: It works!! :) Thank you! I'll attribute the bounty in 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

display("Hello World") # print string
display(df) # print object such as dataframe

clear_output(wait=True) # use this if need to clear the output before display, good for dynamic updates
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can use the carriage return character:

```
from time import sleep
for i in range(10):
    print(i, end='\r')
    sleep(1)
```

Or if you're using Jupyter Notebooks:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
from time import sleep
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    sleep(1)
    clear_output(wait=True)
```