# scikit-learn cross validation not verbose in iPython (Jupyter) notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm running grid search cross validation in an iPython notebook, with verbose set to 10. For some reason there's nothing printed to my notebook when it's running and I'm not sure why. If I interrupt the kernel all of the messages are printed immediately.

Is there a way to make the iPython notebook print in realtime with the updates from grid search cross validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called bufferization of output, look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31153046/1030820. Author decorates stdout of IPython notebook with his own small wrapper, which flushes stdout every time when someone tries to write something new.