# Is there a way to redirect stderr to file in Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

There was a redirect_output function in IPython.utils, and there was a %%capture magic function, but these are now gone, and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571090/ipython-redirecting-output-of-a-python-script-to-a-file-like-bash) on the topic is now outdated.

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
from IPython.utils import io
from __future__ import print_function
with io.redirect_output(stdout=False, stderr="stderr_test.txt"):
    while True:
        print('hello!', file=sys.stderr)
```

Thoughts? For more context, I am trying to capture the output of some ML functions that run for hours or days, and output a line every 5-10 seconds to stderr.  I then want to take the output, munge it, and plot the data.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably try replacing `sys.stderr` with some other file descriptor the same way as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31153046/232371).

```
import sys
oldstderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = open('log.txt', 'w')
# do something
sys.stderr = oldstderr
```

**Update**: starting form Python 3.4, you should consuder using [`contextlib.redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) instead, like this:

```
f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    print('a')
s = f.getvalue()
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Don't forget to `flush()` though.

Answer (score 1):

@Ben, just replacing `sys.stderr` did not work, and the full flush logic [suggested in the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772158/make-ipython-notebook-print-in-real-time/31153046#31153046) was necessary.  But thank you for the pointer as it finally gave me a working version:

```
import sys
oldstderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = open('log.txt', 'w')
class flushfile():
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __getattr__(self,name): 
        return object.__getattribute__(self.f, name)
    def write(self, x):
        self.f.write(x)
        self.f.flush()
    def flush(self):
        self.f.flush()
sys.sterr = flushfile(sys.stderr)
from __future__ import print_function
# some long running function here, e.g. 
for i in range(1000000):
    print('hello!', file=sys.stderr)
sys.stderr = oldstderr
```

It would have been nice if Jupyter kept the `redirect_output()` function and/or the `%%capture` magic.

Comment: This works (but I do feel there ought to be a more concise "built-in" way). To get all output, calling `sys.stderr.flush()` is necessary before switching back to `oldstderr`.

Comment: `_io.TextIOWrapper` already provides `write()` and `flush()`. Not sure why the wrapper class is needed.