# How to save errors from Jupyter Notebook cells to a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to save all output (stdout and all errors) of a cell to a file. To save stdout, I am using the following:

```
import sys
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('test.txt', 'w')
print("Hello World! ")
```

In this case, the output is not displayed and gets saved in the file as expected. To save errors, I used:

```
#Doesn't work
sys.stderr = open('error.txt','w')
print(a) #Should raise NameError
```

When I run this cell, I get the error in the notebook, and not in the file as expected:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-de3efd936845> in <module>()
      1 #Doesn't work
----> 2 sys.stderr = open('error.txt','w')
      3 print("Test")
      4 print(a)

NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

I would like this saved in a file and not shown in the notebook. What is the correct code for this?

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145950/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-stderr-to-file-in-jupyter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* that the problem here is that IPython kernels spawned for the notebook use a [ZMQInteractiveShell](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/bec1a43f7b192895b0b9ca1f5ee1b89b9ff4643b/ipykernel/zmqshell.py#L440) instance, which catches the errors before they make it to stderr, in order to send the error information to the various potential frontends (consoles, jupyter notebooks, etc). See [ipykernel/ipkernel.py#L397-L413](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/7d91110f8f471dbdd3ea65099abcb96a99179557/ipykernel/ipkernel.py#L397-L413) for the code which catches exceptions, then [InteactiveShell._showtraceback](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/65739c0e8bd2b2184a63643358803c57ae7aed42/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L1873-L1879) for the base implementation (print to `sys.stderr`), and [ZMQInteractiveShell._showtraceback](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/bec1a43f7b192895b0b9ca1f5ee1b89b9ff4643b/ipykernel/zmqshell.py#L535-L558) for that used by notebook kernels (send stderr-channel messages over zmq to frontends).

If you're not bothered about getting exact stderr output, you could take advantage of IPython's [existing error logging](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/7d91110f8f471dbdd3ea65099abcb96a99179557/ipykernel/ipkernel.py#L238), which logs errors to a `StreamHandler` with the prefix `"Exception in execute request:"`. To use this, set the ipython log level, and alter the provided handler's stream:

```
import logging
import sys

my_stderr = sys.stderr = open('errors.txt', 'w')  # redirect stderr to file
get_ipython().log.handlers[0].stream = my_stderr  # log errors to new stderr
get_ipython().log.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # errors are logged at info level
```

Alternatively, to get your shell errors to print directly to a file without alteration, you can monkey-patch the `_showtraceback` method to print traceback to file as well as zmq message queues:

```
import sys
import types

# ensure we don't do this patch twice
if not hasattr(get_ipython(), '_showtraceback_orig'):
    my_stderr = sys.stderr = open('errors.txt', 'w')  # redirect stderr to file
    # monkeypatch!
    get_ipython()._showtraceback_orig = get_ipython()._showtraceback

    def _showtraceback(self, etype, evalue, stb):
        my_stderr.write(self.InteractiveTB.stb2text(stb) + '\n')
        my_stderr.flush()  # make sure we write *now*
        self._showtraceback_orig(etype, evalue, stb)

    get_ipython()._showtraceback = types.MethodType(_showtraceback, get_ipython())
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This code however doesn't do the expected:
import logging
import sys

sys.stderr = open('errors.txt', 'w')  # redirect stderr to file
get_ipython().log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

A NameError is not logged in the error log file.

For the second piece of code, this line throws an error:
print(self.InteractiveTB.stb2text(stb), file=sys.stderr)

I could not quite understand this code, hence could not debug the error. Could you run once and check whether it works on your part? I have python 2.7, if that matters.

Comment: Not sure why the first variant isn't working for you, might be worth flushing the file? I'll have to check on PC tomorrow

Comment: The second variant will need a little alteration for python 2 because of the different print syntax, you could try `sys.stderr.write(self.InteractiveTB.stb2text(stb) + '\n')` instead?

Comment: Ok, I've updated both the python snippets to hopefully fix both the problems ;)

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for this, the second solution worked for me